# Get Git commit from "upstream" build in manually triggered Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I have a `Build` job in Jenkins that checks out a specific Git commit and packages it for deployment as artifacts.

There is a later `Deployment` job that takes the built artifacts and actually deploys the code. It also does a sparse Git checkout of a specific directory containing deployment scripts. After successful completion, we write a Git tag.

The problem is that the tag is being written to the `HEAD` of `master`, not to the hash of the commit used for the original upstream build. (`master` is the branch defined in the job configuration.)

Is there a way to get the upstream SCM information if it's not passed directly through a parameterized trigger? I can see commits listed in the `build.xml` file that Jenkins generates in the build directory; is there a way to read this information from the downstream job?

I realize that it's not really "downstream", since it's manually triggered. We do have a selector that defines `UPSTREAM_BUILD` and `UPSTREAM_PROJECT`, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the [Copy Artifact](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin) plugin, you could write a file with the commit hash during the `Build` job and read it back in during the `Deployment` job:

```
# Build
echo ${GIT_COMMIT} > COMMIT_HASH

# Deployment, after copying COMMIT_HASH into the workspace
git checkout $(cat COMMIT_HASH)
```